# Where to get Settings for a Yesod Subsite from?

Tags: yesod

The yesod scaffolding provides `Settings.Extra` which can be used to configure the master site. But in the case of subsites like [gitit2](https://github.com/thkoch2001/gitit2) this can't be used, can it?

Is there any way to put the subsites configuration in the main `config/settings.yml` or should one use a separate yaml file, e.g. `config/gitit2.yml`. How can I easily reuse Yesods config machinery in the latter case?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a settings type in the subsite that has a `FromJSON` instance, and then include that inside the `config/settings.yml` file. Then just include a value of that subsite settings type in your `Extra` data type and things should fall out correctly.